# how can I validate Maven pom tags?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I couldn't understand why the maven-dependency-plugin (included in distributionManagement) was copying all artifacts, until I realized I misspelled the **includeScope** tag:

```
<execution>
  <goals>
    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <includedScope>runtime</includedScope>
```

Neither the validate phase nor maven-enforce-plugin indicated that an invalid tag was present. How can I validate that all tags in my parent pom and children are actual valid tags?

Comment: Simple answer to this: You can't. Any part which is within `<configuration>...</configuration>` is defined by a plugin (or more accurate by the authors) which means there is no option to define a full XSD where you can validate against. Best is to use the documentation reference and copy the information from there or with support of your IDE...

Comment: @khmarbaise ok thanks. Though it seems that this could be achieved by Maven validating against an "effective schema". I'd vote for that

Comment: What do you call `effective schema`?

Comment: @khmarbaise it would be a combination of http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd and the schema of every included plugin

Comment: At which time would you build that?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes I see your point. Maybe in addition to the "help" goal, plugins could provide a "schema" goal. That alone would be so helpful in figuring out what configurations are available. Then the build would parse the pom(s), determine the required plugins, retrieve their schemas, validate the plugin configurations, and then continue